# HTML Code for 4:3 Video

Tags: html, video, vimeo

I have numerous videos on my site that are all 16:9, and my code works great for all screen sizes! Now I need to add 4:3 video. Though it looks good on the desktop, none of the other screen sizes are correct. They add black to the top and bottom of the video.

Here's the working code for 16:9:

```
<div class="resizable_block">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/124950765?></iframe>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .resizable_block {
        width:100%;
        height:0;
        padding-bottom:56.25%;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;}

    figure.preloader .fullwidth,
    .blog.short .preloader .fullwidth, 
    .portfolio_container .preloader .fullwidth, 
    .resize .preloader .fullwidth, 
    .resizable_block .fullwidth {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;}
```

The code for 4:3 that is not working correctly:

```
<div class="resizable_block_43">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/229571095?></iframe>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    .resizable_block_43 {
        width:76%;
        height:0;
        padding-bottom:56.25%;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;}

    .resizable_block_43 .fullwidth {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;}
```

Here's a phone screenshot of the issue:

[image: Phone Screenshot]

I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Of the top of my head, try 75% instead of 56.25%

Comment: I tried raising and lowering that number. It didn't have any impact on the issue.